# Flink Error - Key group is not in KeyGroupRange

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am running a Flink graph using RocksDB as my statebackend.  For one of the join operators in my graph, I get the below exception.  (the actual group #s vary of course from run to run).

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key group 45 is not in
>   KeyGroupRange{startKeyGroup=0, endKeyGroup=42}.

My operator is not too is as follows

```
Source1 -----> Map1A ---> KeyBy--->\___ >
        \----> Map1B ---> KeyBy--->-----> Join1AB ---->
                                                \____>
Source2 ----->------------KeyBy---> -----------------> Join2,1AB ---->
```

The error is thrown for in the Join2,1AB operator which joins (a) the result of Join1AB with the (keyed) source2.

Any ideas what could be causing this?  I have the full stacktrace below, and I understand this is still very vague - but any pointers in the right direction is much appreciated.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key group 45 is not in KeyGroupRange{startKeyGroup=0, endKeyGroup=42}.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.KeyGroupRangeOffsets.computeKeyGroupIndex(KeyGroupRangeOffsets.java:142)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.KeyGroupRangeOffsets.setKeyGroupOffset(KeyGroupRangeOffsets.java:104)
        at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackend$RocksDBFullSnapshotOperation.writeKVStateData(RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.java:664)
        at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackend$RocksDBFullSnapshotOperation.writeDBSnapshot(RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.java:521)
        at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackend$3.performOperation(RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.java:417)
        at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackend$3.performOperation(RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.java:399)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.async.AbstractAsyncIOCallable.call(AbstractAsyncIOCallable.java:72)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.flink.util.FutureUtil.runIfNotDoneAndGet(FutureUtil.java:40)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointRunnable.run(StreamTask.java:897)
        ... 5 more
    [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key group 45 is not in KeyGroupRange{startKeyGroup=0, endKeyGroup=42}.]
```

**EDIT**:   If I change my state backend to be file system (i.e. FsStateBackend), then I get the following stack trace.  Something off with key group indexing.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key group index out of range of key group range [43, 86).
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.NestedMapsStateTable.setMapForKeyGroup(NestedMapsStateTable.java:104)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.NestedMapsStateTable.putAndGetOld(NestedMapsStateTable.java:218)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.NestedMapsStateTable.put(NestedMapsStateTable.java:207)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.NestedMapsStateTable.put(NestedMapsStateTable.java:145)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapValueState.update(HeapValueState.java:72)

<snip user code stack trace>

org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.co.KeyedCoProcessOperator.processElement1(KeyedCoProcessOperator.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor.processInput(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:242)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.TwoInputStreamTask.run(TwoInputStreamTask.java:91)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:263)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:702)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the actual group #s vary of course from run to run`? Do you mean that you change the parameter in `setMaxParallelism` between runs? This is not allowed.

Comment: I just mean the actual error message varies, example:

Key group 45 is not in KeyGroupRange{startKeyGroup=0, endKeyGroup=42}.

Key group 23 is not in KeyGroupRange{startKeyGroup=0, endKeyGroup=21}.

Comment: Oh got it. Could you share configuration of your statebackend? Do you snapshot to some DFS?

Comment: Ok I think I figured out what I was doing wrong.   I'll post as an answer shortly for better formatting.   Thanks much for helping, Dawid!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem was my data objects (POJOs) had an mutable hashcode.  Specifically, the hash code contained Enums.  Example if I have a stream of Cars where the hashcode is composed of the car year and the car type (enum) as below.

```
Car {
   private final CarType carType;
   private final int carYear

   public long hashCode() {
     int result = 17;
     result = 31 * result + carYear;
     result = 31 * result + carType.hasCode();  <---- This is mutable!
   }
}
```

The enum's hashCode is essentially Object.hashCode() (which is memory address dependent).  Subsequently, the hashCode on one machine (or process) will not be the same as on another machine (or process).   This also explains why I only ran into this problem when running in a distributed environment as opposed to running locally.

To resolve this, I changed my hashCode() to be immutable.   Doing String.hashCode() is poor performance, so I may need to optimize that.  But the below definition of Car will fix the problem.

```
Car {
   private final CarType carType;
   private final int carYear

   public long hashCode() {
     int result = 17;
     result = 31 * result + carYear;
     result = 31 * result + carType.name().hasCode();  <---- This is IMMUTABLE!
   }
}
```